# How to use nested middleware in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nested, middleware

I want to make a change from the actual structure of my code. This is the actual code i have:

```js
//index.js
var routes = require('./routes');
var subdomain = require('express-subdomain');

//require express app with settings
var app = require('./app');

//export the application
module.exports = app;

// routes request like endusers-api.mydomain.ext/
app.use(subdomain('endusers-api', routes.apis.endusers));
// routes request like mydomain.ext/
app.use(routes.webapps.endusers);


//routes/index.js
var apis = {endusers: require("./apis/endusers")}
var webapps = {endusers: require("./webapps/endusers")}
var routes = {apis: apis,   webapps: webapps}

module.exports = routes;


//routes/apis/endusers
var express = require('express');
var route = express.Router();
var logger = require('../../lib/logger');

route.get('/', logger("endusers-api-access"), function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({
        "name" : "Endusers API"
    });
});

module.exports = route;


//routes/webapps/endusers.js
var express = require('express');
var route = express.Router();
var logger = require('../../lib/logger');

route.get('/', logger("endusers-webapp-access"), function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('endusers/index', {title: 'Homepage'});
});

module.exports = route;
```

Now I want to change the above code to this (feel free to tell me if this is a good approach of doing things in Node.js or not):

```js
//index.js
var middlewares = require('./middlewares');
var app = require('./app');

module.exports = app;

//i want to change to this
app.use(middlewares.endusersApi);
app.use(middlewares.endusersWebapp);

//Stuff for creating server and listening...


//middlewares/index.js
var middlewares = {
  endusersApi : require("./apis/endusers"), 
  endusersWebapp : require("./webapps/endusers")
}

module.exports = middlewares;


//middlewares/apis/endusers.js
//TODO


//middlewares/webapps/endusers
//TODO
```

How should I write the `TODO` portions above. It look like we will need nested middlewares (a middleware calling another middleware). Please, your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer using by express.Router().all() method.

```js
//middlewares/apis/endusers.js
var routes = require('../../routes');
var express = require('express');
var middleware = express.Router();

middleware.all('/',subdomain('endusers-api', routes.apis.endusers));
//the two next lines are alternatives to the line above 
//middleware = subdomain('endusers-api', routes.apis.endusers); //can assign only one route
//middleware.use(subdomain('endusers-api', routes.apis.endusers)); // can use many routes

module.exports = middleware;


//middlewares/webapps/endusers.js
var routes = require('../../routes');
var express = require('express');
var middleware = express.Router();

middleware.all('/', routes.webapps.endusers);
//the two next lines are alternatives to the line above 
//middleware = routes.webapps.endusers; //can assign only one route
//middleware.use(routes.webapps.endusers); // can use many routes

module.exports = middleware;
```